# xmlrpc server in jython

Tags: jython, xml-rpc

I've tested in jython the xmlrpc code that works in python:
server code:

```
import xmlrpclib
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def is_even(n):
    return n%2 == 0

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(is_even, "is_even")
server.serve_forever()
```

client code:

```
import xmlrpclib

proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000/")
print "3 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(3))
print "100 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(100))
```

I have the errors:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: "<type 'org.xml.sax.SAXException'>:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found\njava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser">
```

I suppose I need to include the xerces library to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It turns oft that I need to include de `xerces` library into the `CLASSPATH`. But what I don't understand is why it's not included by default when I install `Jython`